# Track pundit progress

Tags: support, badges

Is there a way to figure out how close I am to getting the Pundit badge?  Even a way to sort my comments by score would be plenty, but I don't find any way whatsoever to do it, and I don't feel like sorting through hundreds of comments...  Just a curiosity question, really.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133882/am-i-really-a-pundit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone's made an SE Data Query for tracking the pundit badge progress.

http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/75438/whats-my-pundit-badge-progress

That link is for AU, but you can switch the site on the page.

Your user ID will show up in the URL when you go to your profile. Yours is `527350`. Your highest scoring comment is 6. You need 8 more comments with 5 votes.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: Well, you didn't have to tell everyone how far I really am from it... :)  Just kidding, btw.

Comment: @anonymous2 they'll know anyway :p

Comment: Yeah, I know.  You just told them how...  but then, I just asked you how, so who am I blaming...  Btw, totally kidding.  :)   Thanks for the help!

Comment: muahahahaaaa. No problem :p